# Verify that dB1.table1 data elements are properly converted from UTC to EST in the dB2.table2

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Have to verify that the UTC time in  db1.table.a_timestamp converted properly in dB2.table2.a_est_ts to EST time.

```
SELECT dsr_ticket_number, from_utc_timestamp(acknowledgement_timestamp, 'EST') from data_prcy_pds_sanitized.dsr_sor_delete_request  
where dsr_ticket_number, from_utc_timestamp(acknowledgement_timestamp, 'EST')
in (select dsr_ticket_num,acknowledgement_est_ts from data_prcy_dsr_conformed.data_subj_rqst_delete)
```

Gives me an error message : `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:  mismatched input ',' expecting <EOF>(line 2, pos 23)`

Answer (score 0):

Use join instead of IN:

```
select a.dsr_ticket_number, from_utc_timestamp(acknowledgement_timestamp, 'EST') 
  from data_prcy_pds_sanitized.dsr_sor_delete_request a
       left join (select distinct dsr_ticket_num, acknowledgement_est_ts 
                    from data_prcy_dsr_conformed.data_subj_rqst_delete) b
       on a.dsr_ticket_number = b.dsr_ticket_num 
          and from_utc_timestamp(a.acknowledgement_timestamp, 'EST') = b.acknowledgement_est_ts 
 where b.dsr_ticket_num is not null
 --or to find records which are not in second table
 --use WHERE b.dsr_ticket_num is null
```